# C# building menus at runtime, commandHandlers and hashtable

Tags: c#, menu, menuitem

I am (very) new to C#, and I am trying to implement an existing application metamodel in this language. In this metamodel, a "menus" table holds a combination of forms and actions, indicating, for each form, which actions should be available.

I am then able to use this "menus" datasource to build and display a form's specific MenuStrip at runtime. Each item in the menu (ToolStripMenuItem) holds the corresponding 'action' string. Clicking on this item should launch the corresponding command.

So now is the question: how do I link the action string of the ToolStripmenuItem to the corresponding command?

My first idea was to maintain a HashTable containing the action string as a key, and the method to be executed, like this:

a generic CommandHandler method:

```
delegate void CommandHandler(string[] args);
```

and, in my main module, a HashTable looking like this

```
myHashCommandTable.Add 
    (   "issueThePurchaseOrder", 
        new CommandHandler(PurchaseOrder.IssueThePurchaseOrder))
```

I could then run the corresponding command at runtime:

```
if myHashCommandTable.ContainsKey(myActionString)
{
    ((CommandHandler)myHashCommandTable[myActionString])
}
```

But this would force me to maintain this HashTable "by hand", and it could quickly become a source of trouble for the developpers, and instability for the application! Any other idea?

Comment: so everybody told me about reflection .. As the concept is new to me, I am going to have a look at it. It already sounds better than my original proposal. Dommage nobody wrote down some lines of code ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could just store the name of target method in your data source and then use reflection to look it up at run-time. Passing data to the target method would be tricky, but that's just one more exciting challenge for you to overcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can allow the model to hold both action names and methods - a few different ways.

```
<action name="issueThePurchaseOrder" run="PurchaseOrder.IssueThePurchaseOrder"/>
```

When you read the file, either use reflection to find your run command,

Or have a second table in code mapping "run commands" to methods.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @itsme86, really
Use Actionstring with Reflection to find the method on the form. If you wanteda higher level of abstraction ActionString could be an attribute value, and you could decorate the method it excutes with it.

A nice bit of fall out from either is you could add a bit of test code to compare menu items and actions, and look for mismatches between the meta data and the implementation.